# Maven optional dependency management possible?

Tags: maven, dependency-management

Given the following structure:

```
...
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-bom</artifactId>
    <version>${my-bom-version}</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>

<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>optionalDependency</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>skipTests</name>
        <value>!true</value>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
         <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
         <artifactId>some-module-in-my-group-id</artifactId>
         <optional>true</optional>
         <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
     </dependencies>
   </profile>
 </profiles>
 ...
```

I want to only load anything from my.group.id when i build the project with tests. But in the given structure, built with

```
-dSkipTests=true
```

my-bom allways gets loaded anyway. Is it possible to surpress this in a way that the bom version only gets loaded from nexus when the project gets build with tests?

Comment: The scope test is intended to have the appropriate dependency only available on classpath for the tests. It will not being packaged into resulting jar/wars etc. So there no need to go such complicated path...

Comment: Thanks, i didnt see the simple solution.